# Iterating through my followers so as to pick up their messages from message database

Tags: php

I am trying to get messages to display like this :
MY FIREND - LAST MESSAGE
MY OTHER FRIEND - LAST MESSAGE.

But whenever i try, it only shows just one friend and the last message, leaving the others out. here is the code;

```
if($view == ""){
echo "<div class='messagebox' style='height:auto; width:300px;'><ul>";
/*here i selected from my friends and then i would search in 
my message database if any of this friends who am following sent me a message or recieved a message from me, therefore
it should output the friend and the message*/
$result = querysql("SELECT user FROM friends WHERE friend = '$user'");
if($result->num_rows){
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    for($i = 0; $i<$num; $i++){
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $friends = $row['user'];

                  $result1 = querysql("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever ='$user' 
                    OR sender='$user' ORDER BY time DESC");
                    $rows = $result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    $senderr = $rows['sender'];
                    $recieverr = $rows['reciever'];
                    $mess = $rows['message'];
                    if($friends == $senderr || $friends == $recieverr){
                    echo <<<_END
                    <li><div>
                    <a href='messages.php?view=$friends'>$friends</a> : $mess
                    </div></li>
               _END;
            }

            }

            }
         echo '</ul></div>'; 
          }
```

Comment: You're not looping over the results of your second query. If you don't want to, add a `LIMIT 1` to the end, it will be more efficient. Also your `_END;` needs to be at the very start of a line, it won't work properly indented as you show in your code.

Comment: the limit helps to give the latest message for each friend but yet it displays the name of the friends as it was in the friends db accompanied by a message for each, the problem is the friends name that is echoed

Comment: i looped through but it only displays the message with a different user